# SQL query to map between tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following columns:

Table `abc`:

```
table | current_core | Desc           | target_Core | Desc
------------------------------------------------------------------------
POS   | AM           | Assistant mgr  | ASmgr       | Assistent Manager
LOC   | 1            | NEW DELHI      | NEWDEL      | NEW DELHI
GRADE | CLASS-1      | Officer        | Ofcr        | Officer
```

Now I have a table with these codes:
For example:

`consolidated_table`:

```
position_code | location_code | start_date  | end_date    | person_no 
AM            | 10            | 01-jan-2010 | 01-jan-2018 | A1
AM            | 1             | 01-jan-2010 | 01-jan-2018 | A2
```

Now I want to write a query such that all the rows like `start_date`, `end_date` `person_no` are picked from `consolidated_table` but for `position_code` and `location_code` the `target_core` from `abc` is picked against the `current_core` which is equal to the codes given in `consolidated_table`.

I have written a query somewhat like:

```
SELECT
  position_map.target_core position_code,
  location_map.target_code location_code
  stag.start date,
  stag.end_date,
  stag.person_no 
FROM consolidated_table stag,
  abc position_map,
  abc location_map
WHERE position_map.current_core = position_map.position_code
  AND position_map.table = 'POS'
  AND location_map.current_code = location_map.location_code
  AND position_map.table = 'LOC'
```

But this query is fetching less rows. For location_code 10 in `consolidated_table` there is no data in `abc`. I want in this case the location code is only retrieved.

Comment: Change your joining conditions from `WHERE` which implies an `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two conditions in your starting query are wrong:

```
position_map.current_core = position_map.position_code
location_map.current_code = location_map.location_code
```

The `position_map` and `location_map` aliases refer to table abc, which has neither `position_code` nor `location_code` nor `current_code`.  I suppose you intend for these to be predicates for joining `abc` to `consolidated_table` (twice).  One possibility for that is presented below, though if it's indeed what you want then the design of table `abc` is severely flawed.

You also say ...

> For location_code 10 in consolidated_table there is no data in abc. I want in this case the location code is only retrieved.

... by which I guess you mean you want to include at least one row for each combination of rows from `consolidated_table` and `abc` that match on the position criterion, even if no rows from `abc` match on the location criterion.  That would involve an outer join.

Putting it together, it seems like you want something along these lines:

```
select
  pos.target_core as position_code,
  coalesce(loc.target_core, c.location_code) as location_code,
  c.start_date,
  c.end_date,
  c.person_no
from
  consolidated_table c
  join abc as pos on pos.current_core = c.position_code
  left join abc as loc on loc.target_core = c.location_code and loc.table = 'LOC'
where
  pos.table = 'POS'
```

Do not overlook the `coalesce()` in the select list and the inclusion of the `loc.table` condition as part of a join predicate instead of in the filter predicate.  The former accounts for the fact that where there is no match on the location criterion, all result columns drawn from table `loc` will be `NULL`.  The latter reflects my understanding for the join you want to do -- outer joins are much more sensitive than inner joins with respect to whether conditions are expressed in the join predicate or in the filter predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, in addition to having some column names incorrect, there were some other syntax errors as well in the original query posted.

```
SELECT
 position_map.target_core position_code,
 location_map.target_core location_code,
 stag.start_date,
 stag.end_date,
 stag.person_no 
FROM consolidated_table stag
LEFT JOIN abc position_map
 ON stag.position_code = position_map.current_core
 AND position_map.table = 'POS'
LEFT JOIN abc location_map
 ON  stag.location_code = location_map.current_core
 AND position_map.table = 'LOC'
```